# How to show Wiener measure induces basic properties of Brownian motion?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

page 19 of http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr64.pdf gives a defintion of Wiener measure Ft1,t2,..,tk. 
But how can we show it is a probability measure and it satisfies the consistency condition given in Kolmogrov extension theorem ? Also , how to show the independence and normal distribution part? These are Excercise 1 a,b,c following the difinition. 
Could anyone show me how to do it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Come! You would be unable to prove this is probability measure, to begin with?

Comment: @did but how to get measure of whole space is 1 ? there seems no defintion for little p in the notes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $p$ is on page 9 of the notes.